# Cameranext not saving pictures

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera, cache

I am using a non-rooted Oneplus One (cm12, all patches). I have to admit that I really dont use the camera very often, but on a family trip yesterday i noticed, the pictures i took  were **not** saved, except for two of them... Since it is impossible to recreate the pictures from our trip I am searching for any other alternative to get them back.

I found a bunch of topics on oneplus' support forums like this: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/stock-camera-app-not-saving-pictures.286705/

Basically saying its not a bug, its a feature. While I think those answers are disputable at least, my question would be if there is any hope to restore the pictures (or at least parts of the album) from the cameras cache - which is about 60MB as I post this question.

Rooting the phone to get access to those cache files would not be a Problem if needed. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

If the files got cached on sd card or internal storage, Android 5 + Never delete images fully..
Use a new photo recovery App like DiskDigger .. This will pull your images from any sector of the accessible storage devices without root.

Comment: I'll give diskdigger a try, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Note that this can only work if the pictures had been saved and then deleted. If they were never saved, there's nothing to restore from. Hence put some emphasis on the very first word of this answer: "IF". I've never heard a camera caches pictures it does not save – but there are at least slight chances the bug is working that way. Secondly, this will only work if those files were on the external SD card. For internal memory, you'd need to clone the partitions and use some forensic software against the clones (e.g. TestDisk).

Comment: DriveDigger found only the pictures that got saved normally. I think its like Izzy suggests, if the pictures dont get saved, there is nothing to restore from. Bad bug, those pictures can never be retaken... I'm gonna check twice now if a photo is saved.

Answer (score 0):

P.S

All CYANOGEN MOD VERSIONS FROM VERSION 11 UPWARDS INCLUDE ROOT ACCESS AS PART OF THEIR PRIVACY GUARD FEATURE INSIDE PRIVACY IN SETTINGS...

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

[image: step4]

[image: step5]

[image: step6]